# javascript onDeleted event after deleting row from telerik grid

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

my telerik grid fill via ajax. My delete method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult _AjaxModelDelete(CarModel obj)
    {
        Model m = dm.GetModelById(obj.Id);
        dm.DeleteModel(m);
        List<Model> res = dm.GetModelsByVendorId(m.VendorId).ToList();
        return View(new GridModel<CarModel>
        {
            Data = res.Select(x => new CarModel { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name })
        });
    }
```

Grid have client side event onDelete but I need reload grid on event onDeleted. how solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try calling the [ajaxRequest](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#ajaxRequest) method to initiate a refresh of the grid data.